# How to limit keyboard input to letters only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events

I'm working on a solution that basically shows/hides a "Find" button based on whether or not the user has typed anything in the input. Currently, even typing a space in the input is enough to trigger the button to show, but I want to ensure that only a letter (A-Z) on first input makes the button appear.

There's a lot of needless code involved so I'll only include the snippet where the magic needs to happen:

```
  const ccceValues = object.attributeCollection.questions.reduce(
    (acc, attribute) => {
      const fieldEntry = ccceBeInformedFieldMap.get(attribute.key);

      if (fieldEntry) {
        // CHECK NEEDS TO GO BEFORE THIS ASSIGNMENT
        acc[fieldEntry] = attribute.value;
      }

      return acc;
    },
    ccceInput
  );
```

The check needs to happen before the assignment on the `if` statement so that we only assign `acc[fieldEntry] = attribute.value` if the first keyboard input has been a letter. Is this possible?

Ps `attribute.value` is. equal to the keyboard input.

Comment: What is the default value of the reduce

Answer (score 1):

If you have the key value itself, you could use regex to verify if the value is a letter:

```js
const keyOfB = 'b';
const keyOf3 = '3';

const alphaRegex = /[a-zA-Z]/;

console.log(alphaRegex.test(keyOfB));
console.log(alphaRegex.test(keyOf3))
```

Comment: finding that it seems to default to true regardless (even on render) so the above is never returning false, even on numbers. must be something happening higher up. thanks for the help!